# Bootstrap の Collapse クラスでパネルを展開した状態で eb ページを開くようにしたい

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap の Collapse クラスを使ってパネルを作ってます。
パネルのタイトルをクリックして開け閉めをするところまではできましたが、URL にパラメータを指定することで該当のパネルのみを開いた状態にする方法がありましたら教えていただけますと有難いです。

例えば `https://example.com/index.com#id_10` と指定すると、id_10 のパネルのみが開いた状態で、eb ページが開かれるようにしたいです。

Answer (score 1):

ページ読み込み後に

```
$(location.hash).collapse('show');
```

を実行するのではいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ご連絡いただきどうも有難うございます。
試したところ、正しく動きました。 ご丁寧に回答いただきまして、誠に有難うございました。